# In AstroNvim .js extraction files autoimport and snippet sometimes do not work

Tags: neovim

I can not type in shorthand code snippets always only .js and .ts extraction files and sometimes auto import .js or .ts extraction files doesn't work, even  html tag auto suggest does not show auto emmite.

on the other hand, .jsx or .tsx extraction file auto import and snippet work well.

How can I fix this issue?

I tried update AstroNvim and other copule of things. I do into .jsx snippets,auto import, auto html emmite so one i can do into .js or .ts file as well.